# What is the meaning of suchness?

Tags: dhammas

We can contemplate on the suchness , thisness and thusness…(I have seen some members of the site use the word “suchness” often)

What is the meaning of suchness as against the meaning of thisness and thusness?

Comment: you know the hindi word for truth is sach?